# Automatic authentication for samba shares

Tags: networking, server, samba

My network consists of an Ubuntu 14.04 server sharing folders via samba to countless other Windows clients on the network.

I'm tired of connecting to the server and it asking for a user name and password. On my network there's no need for this.

**My Problem** : In my Windows enviro I can access all the file of the server. However, I have a backup program that won't connect to the server files because of authentication problems.

**Short and simple** : How do I turn off user names and passwords in my smb.conf file???

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the share as public. Edit the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file, and use this template:

```
[public]
   path = /usr/somewhere/else/public
   public = yes
   only guest = yes
   writable = yes
   printable = no
```

Beware, disable authentication at your own risk. This is accessible by anyone. Use the `writable` flag to secure it to read only.